# Get first match in series, R

Tags: r

I have vector contain 1 and 0

```
a <- c(0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0)
```

I need get trigger, when i getting first 1, when after 0 i get 1 again, need get trigger again.

That is, when I come across group 1, I need to mark the first 1 in this group with some kind of trigger. Group is always detached 0.

The final result should look like this:

```
NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `base R` solution with indexing based on differences can be:

```
#Data
a <- c(0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0)
index <- c(0,diff(a))
a[which(index!=1)] <- NA
```

Output:

```
a
 [1] NA NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA  1 NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `rleid` from `data.table` and `duplicated`.

```
b <- +(!duplicated(data.table::rleid(a)) & a == 1)
b
#[1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0

b[b == 0] <- NA
b
#[1] NA NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA  1 NA NA NA
```

`rleid(a)` creates a group number for every change in `a`, `!duplicated` would return `TRUE` for every first match and by using `a == 1` we restrict it to only for values = 1.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work

```
c(NA, ifelse(a[-1] == 1 & a[-length(a)] == 0, 1, NA))
# [1] NA NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA  1 NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R approach:

```
> a <- c(0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0)
> a[which(a > lag(a))] <- 1
> a[-which(a > lag(a))] <- NA
> a
 [1] NA NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA  1 NA NA NA
>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
+(NA^duplicated(rleid(a)) & NA^!a)
#[1] NA NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA  1 NA NA NA
```